# How to describe flow types for Object.entries()

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have an object and I want to use Object.entries() over it. I have an error when I try so

```
const params: Array<Array<string>> = Object.entries(parameters);
```

then I have error

> Cannot assign Object.entries(...) to params because:
>
> - tuple type [1] is incompatible with array type [2] in array element.
> - array type [2] has an unknown number of elements, so is incompatible with tuple type [1] in array element.

I tried to google and found a couple of issues but it didn't help

Comment: This is wrong: `Array<Array<string>> `

Comment: well, I guessed it.
I would like to know how it should look lile

Comment: Try `Array<[string, mixed]>`